# I would like to use the Content Search Web Part to only display Document Libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online

So I been using advanced query builder to accomplish to only display document libraries because I have a workflow that generates numerous packages.

path:"Site URL" (contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary)

This only displays a couple of libraries, but also includes the general document libraries, how can I narrow my query to search only "FY" in the title of the document libraries thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
path:"Site URL" (contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary) Title:FY
```

Similar to the "path" property, the colon in the query (:) means "Contains".

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
FY path:"Site URL" (contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary)
```